# make UIScrollview scroll

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have porblem that my `UIScrollView` does not scroll I don't think that is a problem with iphone emulator. Here is my way to construct `UIScrollView`:

```
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES; // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

and I add `UILabel` to it, to which later I add some info from xml.

```
labeL = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1000)];
labeL.numberOfLines = 0;
labeL.text =@"";
[scrollView addSubview:labeL];
```

this is how I add value to `UILabel`:

```
vypisObratString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:labeL.text];
if (turnOver) {
    turnOver = NO;
    [vypisObratString appendString:@"----------------"];
    [vypisObratString appendString:@"\n"];
    labeL.text = vypisObratString;
}
```

But when I compile the program it writes the corect values but the last line is like this:

```
12.1.2010...
```

and it does not scroll. Why? What I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your issue is with setting the size of the scroll view which needs to be larger than the size of the iphone (i.e. it needs to know that there is some area outside the phone display to scroll to). 
Something along these lines:

```
UIScrollView *tempScrollView=(UIScrollView *)self.view;
tempScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(800,800);
```

That should be all you need to make it scroll.

Cheers

James

Comment: Thank It start to scroll.Your answer was right but now it does not scroll all of my UILabel which is CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1000) has it something with CGSizeMake(600,400)?

Comment: Yes - sorry have updated the code above. You need to set the CGSizeMake parameters to fit the size of the area you want to be scrollable.